# Surfacing key information in Azure DevOps - pivot options appear limited?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, dashboard

Currently trying to surface key information around the projects in our organisation.  I want to show a breakdown of work items assigned, estimated time, and completed time per individual.  I thought I could do this with the chart widget, and I can if I have 3 different pivots, but it seems very limited.  I don't seem to be able to adjust the order of the column series (status) to what I want. I can adjust based on the values - e.g. estimates but then the next chart has that status in a completely different order because it's sorting on something different.

Is there another widget I should use, or is Azure DevOps not capable of handling this?  Do I have to use Excel or PowerBI instead??

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? Feel free to let me know if you're still blocked, I'll try my best to help :)

Comment: Sorry @Walter, I've been looking into something else.  I have tried the widget and it works to a degree, but I think it's limited, firstly by the display (that 4 by 4 area isn't big enough in all honesty, and it's probably a level behind what's needed) and also by the queries (the time taken to set it up is quite excessive) so it looks like I may be better using Excel, at least until I get DevOps working a bit better for us.  Thanks for your reply though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use “chart for work items” widget. Please select chart type as Pivot table. For example, here is my configuration of the "Chart for work items" widget: [image]

You can see the Original Estimate assigned to each user in this widget:
[image]